# Representation for meaning of a text document

Tags: natural-language, text-mining, text-summarization

Does anyone know a technique to represent meaning of a given text document, so that two documents having same meaning will have same representations?

**Note:** Typical systems like vectorization methods are not suitable for this because they only consider presence of vocabulary of the text, not the ordering of words.

Comment: You are probably looking for something like semantic embeddings.

Comment: Is there any paper or something published related to semantic embeddings?? can you post something regarding this??

Comment: Latent dirichlet allocation is used to detect topics in documents. You may find it useful.

Comment: I suggest you do a first round of Google searching yourself and then ask specific questions. LDA as Ian mentioned is also worth checking out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We might need to know what exactly is your goal.

Meaning of a text needs to be a complex structure (whatever approach). So if you want two document with the same meaning to have *exactly* the same meaning representation, you need to go for a full semantic modelling using some sophisticated approach involving knowledge representation etc.

But how do you measure how much the meaning of two texts is the same / similar?

Typical representationl approach is to have some metric of similarity like cosing distance of two vectors. BTW there is a doc2vec that produces vector representation of the whole text. And doc2vec does care about the context of the words, maybe not strictly about word order but their proximities.